Java Flink NoClassDefFoundError org/apache/flink/shaded/guava30/com/google/common/io/Closer
I have a Java 21 application that uses Apache Flink (version 1.20.0) dependencies for filtering kafka stream.
When I try executing my program I get the following error:
[flink-pekko.actor.default-dispatcher-5] INFO org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.ExecutionGraph - Source: Wikimedia Recent Change Events -> Filter -> Sink: Writer -> Sink: Committer (12/20) (b06737fae3a29dd6d5031f24d0e01683_cbc357ccb763df2852fee8c4fc7d55f2_11_0) switched from INITIALIZING to FAILED on 114b44f3-53af-41a6-bc97-a040192436ae @ localhost (dataPort=-1).
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/flink/shaded/guava30/com/google/common/io/Closer
    at org.apache.flink.connector.kafka.sink.KafkaWriter.<init>(KafkaWriter.java:109)
    at org.apache.flink.connector.kafka.sink.KafkaSink.createWriter(KafkaSink.java:111)
    at org.apache.flink.connector.kafka.sink.KafkaSink.createWriter(KafkaSink.java:57)
    at org.apache.flink.api.connector.sink2.Sink.createWriter(Sink.java:78)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.operators.sink.StatefulSinkWriterStateHandler.createWriter(StatefulSinkWriterStateHandler.java:122)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.operators.sink.SinkWriterOperator.initializeState(SinkWriterOperator.java:148)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamOperatorStateHandler.initializeOperatorState(StreamOperatorStateHandler.java:147)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractStreamOperator.initializeState(AbstractStreamOperator.java:294)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.RegularOperatorChain.initializeStateAndOpenOperators(RegularOperatorChain.java:106)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.restoreStateAndGates(StreamTask.java:858)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.lambda$restoreInternal$5(StreamTask.java:812)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTaskActionExecutor$1.call(StreamTaskActionExecutor.java:55)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.restoreInternal(StreamTask.java:812)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.restore(StreamTask.java:771)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.runWithSystemExitMonitoring(Task.java:970)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.restoreAndInvoke(Task.java:939)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.doRun(Task.java:763)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:575)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.flink.shaded.guava30.com.google.common.io.Closer
    ... 19 more

I have tried adding the following dependency to my pom.xml as a way to solve this issue:
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-shaded-guava</artifactId>
            <version>31.1-jre-17.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

But I still get the same error.

I was able to fix it by using compatible versions of flink for flink dependencies and flink-connector-kafka. Using flink-shaded-guava was not necessary for that.
This are my dependencies before:
    <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>21</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>21</maven.compiler.target>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

    <main.class>org.taulin.WikimediaStreamFilterApp</main.class>

    <flink.version>1.20.0</flink.version>
    <flink.connector.version>1.17.2</flink.connector.version>
    <avro.version>1.11.1</avro.version>
    <slf4j.version>2.0.16</slf4j.version>
    <guice.version>7.0.0</guice.version>
    <lombok.version>1.18.34</lombok.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Flink -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-java</artifactId>
        <version>${flink.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-clients</artifactId>
        <version>${flink.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-streaming-java</artifactId>
        <version>${flink.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-connector-kafka</artifactId>
        <version>${flink.connector.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-avro-confluent-registry</artifactId>
        <version>${flink.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-avro</artifactId>
        <version>${flink.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-shaded-guava</artifactId>
        <version>31.1-jre-17.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

These are my dependencies now:
    <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>21</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>21</maven.compiler.target>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

    <main.class>org.taulin.WikimediaStreamFilterApp</main.class>

    <flink.version>1.17.2</flink.version>
    <avro.version>1.11.1</avro.version>
    <slf4j.version>2.0.16</slf4j.version>
    <guice.version>7.0.0</guice.version>
    <lombok.version>1.18.34</lombok.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Flink -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-java</artifactId>
        <version>${flink.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-clients</artifactId>
        <version>${flink.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-streaming-java</artifactId>
        <version>${flink.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-connector-kafka</artifactId>
        <version>${flink.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-avro-confluent-registry</artifactId>
        <version>${flink.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-avro</artifactId>
        <version>${flink.version}</version>
    </dependency>

